# How can I change buffer local key binding C-h, C-x, M-x in term raw mode?

Tags: key-bindings, term, ansi-term, buffer-local

I'm running a specific console application in a term window (char/raw mode).
This application has no need for `C-h`, `C-x`, and `M-x`,
so they should just do what they always do in Emacs.
However, I don't want to change the behaviour of other term mode buffers, i.e. this should be buffer local.
Any idea, how to do that?

E.g. `(term-set-escape-char ?\C-x)` seems to change all term buffers, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. To run `M-x` and other Emacs commands in term buffers, simply switch to `term-line-mode`.

Comment: It is cumbersome to have to switch modes first, and in my specific case it shouldn't be necessary. More key presses...

Comment: Well, but then why do you use `term`? Use `shell` or `eshell`.

Comment: AFAIK, neither `shell` nor `eshell` do provide any terminal emulation features. I'm running a console application, that needs a terminal (think *vi* or *mutt*). Only it does not need `C-h`, `C-x`, or `M-x`, so I would like to leave those keys to Emacs.

Comment: I'm suggestig that what you're trying to ahieve defeats the purpose of a terminal emulator. A terminal emulator should send input events directly without interceptions, right? And, as mentioned, you can toggle between char and term mode. `Eshell` is able to give you the illusion that it runs terminal-based programs but in reality it just offloads to `(ansi)-term`.

Comment: A terminal emulator should send input events directly, but not necessarily without interceptions. E.g. `term` intercepts `C-c`. If I run a specific program and I know, that this program does not use `C-h`, `C-x`, or `M-x` it makes life much easier, if I can use them as Emacs intented, without cumbersome mode switching.

Comment: You convinced me. I found out that some keybindings are not intercepted when you hit the `C-x` prefix. For instance, in `term-mode` give `C-x M-x` a try.

Comment: Alternatively, you could do `(define-key term-raw-map [?\M-x] 'execute-extended-command)`, but I don't know how to turn it into a buffer local binding.

Comment: Yes, I tried that and some similar approaches, but all mess at least with other `term` buffers, which is not so nice. It looks like `term` might not be the "cleanest" part of Emacs, i.e. it has some hacks in it. That makes it much harder to build on it than other modes. At some point, I'll try `vterm`. It is supposed to be faster and more complete than `term`. Maybe it is also better hackable?

Comment: I had the same feeling while briefly looking at the source code of `term`. I have never used `vterm`, so I can't comment on that.